# How to select a file without opening it?

Tags: filesystem, 14.10

This is probably a quite trivial question, but I cannot seem to find the answer on-line. I set my file browser to single click opening as it is easier to work with, but, since clicking opens the file or folder, I can't seem to find the way to select a single file or folder...

Comment: And with a rightclick? ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind With right-click, the context menu additionally opens, but I only want to select the file, nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using pantheon file manager which  also open file on single click.

So if I have to select a file I have to

- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click on file
- Select the the file by drawing selection box by dragging the mouse.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It surprises me that hovering doesn't work, but you can drag to select a small area covering only that file, the way you'd drag to select multiple files.

Comment: I remember hovering to work previously, but I cant seem to find the option anymore. Not in nemo nor nautilus

Comment: @PeterRaeves Associated feature request: https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/385

Answer (score 1):

Using the keyboard (in Nautilus):

- Open the window
- Type the first character of the file or folder you want to select. A rectangle will appear and the corresponding file will be selected.
- If there are more files / folders with the same first character, type the next character to refine the definition

As a nice "bonus" some information on the folder is displayed as well.

[image]